# grep url pattern matching

Tags: linux, apache, grep

I'm looking to count url pattern in access log like

```
action.php?show_page=next&offset=1&xyzzzzz
```

Note that I need all url where offset values are between 1 to 9. Examples:

```
action.php?show_page=next&offset=1&xyzzzzz
action.php?show_page=next&offset=2&xyzzzzz
action.php?show_page=next&offset=3&xyzzzzz
.............
action.php?show_page=next&offset=9&xyzzzzz
```

This is what I tried:

```
grep "action.php?show_page=next" access.log.2 | grep "offset=[1-9]&"| wc -l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `grep`:

```
grep -oc "action.php?show_page=next&offset=[1-9]&xyzzzzz" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You should scape the "?" of the first grep.
try with the regex:

```
action.php\?show_page=next&offset=[1-9]
```